# Only apply neovim rule to one folder

Tags: vim, configuration, git, nvim

I have a notes folder that is also a git repo with an `autocmd` in my `init.vim` set to auto-commit to the repo every time the file gets saved. This behavior is undesirable in git repo folders with actual code, so I was wondering how to selectively apply the rule to only one folder.

Comment: It might help to see how the autocmd is currently written, but it *should* work just to include the filepath when specifying what files you want the rule to apply to, `autocmd BufWritePost /path/to/notes/folder/* !git ...`.

Comment: Thanks @frabjous, that worked :)